# Setting indicator variables to equal 1 or 0

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I have to set HIGPA to equal 1 if the gpa is greater than 3, and if it is less, then HIGPA must equal 0. I am using R.

gpa is already a variable in the data. HIGPA is not.
So far I have made HIGPA a factor of gpa.

```
> HIGPA<-factor(gpa)
```

After this step I am lost.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: what if gpa is exactly 3? Do you actually need it to be a factor, or do you just need it to be 0-1 if gpa is <3 or > 3?

Comment: If gpa is 3 or greater HIGPA should be set to 1. If gpa is anything lower than 3 then HIGPA should be set to 0.

Comment: answer edited to incorporate the equality

Answer (score 3):

You should post some example data... like so:

```
gpa <- c(2, 3.68, 2.96, 2.85, 2.67, 3.26, 2.55, 2.84, 3.09, 2.79)
```

Here's one way:

```
as.numeric(gpa >= 3)
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

So we can put that into HIGPA

```
HIGPA <- as.numeric(gpa >= 3)
```

If you really need it to be a factor, you can `factor` or `as.factor` it at the end.